# MVVM : fetch data from server and notify item

Tags: android, search, mvvm, android-room, android-livedata

I will take an example to explain my problem : in a search screen, I need to search for a big list of movies.
I can bookmark each movie, so I need to notify my item in my recycler, **here is my problem**.

**Do I need to put every movies searched in room database** and it will be simple after for the notify with MVVM & DiffUtils?

Because, when I used MVP, I created a small database with MovieId and a boolean for bookmark, and when the user bookmark a movie, I run through in my items in adapter and notify the concerned item. But this solution is very ugly now with MVVM.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just for the search screen you don't need to save data to local database. Instead of that you can just bind one list to RecyclerView and update it with another list from API using DiffUtils.

Comment: Ok but if I handle for example bookmarks, so I need to store in database which movies are bookmarked. So, when I bookmark one movie, what I need to do? Call again my server and map my items, it's overkill no?

Comment: Nope, just update the ui and store bookmars locally.

Comment: Yes and when you said "update the UI" you mean, get the liveData, run through the items and find the item by id and notify it. I do this with mvp but I think it's boilerplate :/

Comment: Another not very good approach is to have custom view which knows only id of the element and is bound to the bookmarks livedata/db source